# I am trying show roles related to user using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show roles related to the user but unfortuntly not showing roles in the selection option related to the user please help me how can resolve that?

**controller**

```
public function edit(User $user)
  {
    $data = [
      'roles' => Role::where('name', '!=', 'super-admin')->get(),
      'users' => $user->load('roles'),
    ];
    return view('cms.user_management.edit', $data);
  }
```

**html view**

```
              <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="roles[]" 
                     multiple="multiple">
                           <option disabled >please select</option>
                          @foreach($roles as $key => $value)
                          <option value="{{ $value->name }}" {{ $users->id == 
                   $value->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $value->name }}</option>                                
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
```

Comment: are you using spatie permissions package ?

Comment: yes dear i am using https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction

Comment: You can use as in their documents $user->getRoleNames(); via https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage

Comment: ok dear but please guide me a/c to my code thanks.

Comment: Is my answer working ?

Comment: I have got  roles related user ['designer'] but please i  confused how can i show roles in selection option ?

Comment: just check is rolls array contain certain roll of the user and then you can echo the selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change you code as below to retriew all roles that assigned to a user

```
'roles' => $user->getRoleNames();
```

`$user->getRoleNames()` will return array of roles assigned to that user like `['role01','role02']`

So then you just need to loop that array inside blade and make required conditions  .

Find more regarding their  [basic usages](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage)